# parse regex fuzzy logic rules

Tags: regex, rule, fuzzy

There are some fuzzy logic string rules like:

> IF Input1.A AND Input2.B Then Output1.A
>
> IF Input1.A AND (NOT Input2.B) AND Input3.C Then Output1.A

I want to capture groups after AND and after Then.

and also capture (NOT Input2.B) with its parentheses.

and also after IF.

Comment: I want it in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/LrNBaJ/2/):

```
(?:IF|AND|THEN\s*)(?<token>.+?)(?=\s*(?:AND|THEN|$))
```

"match a keyword, then reluctantly match anything, only up to the next AND/THEN/EOL"

and this will work in Python:

```
(?:IF|AND|THEN\s*)(?P<token>.+?)(?=\s*(?:AND|THEN|$))
```